# Create table from json in sql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

While working with sql I faced the following json in the table. I would like to transform it to a separate table that has one column for messages and one for the commander. Is there any function to do it? I am working in postgresql if it makes any difference. I am basically trying to form a table to compare the commander values with thee names of the commanders from other table. Therefore, if there is an easy way to extract the names of the commanders from son without forming table that will be good too.

```
{
    "log": [
        {
            "message": "Cute dino!",
            "commander": "Sam"
        },
        {
            "message": "Cute dino!",
            "commander": "Joe"
        },
        {
            "message": "Cute dino!",
            "commander": "Bob"
        }
    ],
    "features": {
        "food": "1",
        "fuel": "0",
        "minerals": "1",
        "dinosaurs": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a separate table. You can query and index jsonb columns. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements()` to turn the array into rows and then use that as the source for a CREATE TABLE statement:

```
create table data
as
with input (value) as (
  values ('{
      "log": [
          {
              "message": "Cute dino!",
              "commander": "Sam"
          },
          {
              "message": "Cute dino!",
              "commander": "Joe"
          },
          {
              "message": "Cute dino!",
              "commander": "Bob"
          }
      ],
      "features": {
          "food": "1",
          "fuel": "0",
          "minerals": "1",
          "dinosaurs": "1"
      }
  }'::jsonb)
) 
select t.log ->> 'message' as message,
       t.log ->> 'commander' as commander
from input
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(value -> 'log') as t(log)
```